# Combining multiple rows to get value in BigQuery

Tags: null, google-bigquery

I am having a problem similar to this table below

```
id         phonenumber    email          name 
A0001       123456789     null           null
A0001          null       abc@xyz.com   null
A0001          null       null           Adam
```

I wonder if there is a way to combine all rows into 1 and take the value from the not null row into one row
This is the result I am looking for

```
id         phonenumber    email          name 
A0001       123456789     abc@xyz.com   Adam
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is something like this:

```
with data as (
  select 'A0001' as id, 123456789 as phonenumber, null as email, null as name union all
  select 'A0001', null, 'abc@xyz.com', null union all
  select 'A0001', null, null, 'Adam'
)
select id, max(phonenumber) as phonenumber, max(email) as email, max(name) as name
from data
group by 1
```

If your table has multiple rows with different phonenumbers per id, for example, then you might not get the intended results.